# Unreachable code with multiple catch statements

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, unreachable-code, catch-block

Why does line 2 compile while line 3 does not?
spit() throws a HurtException that has already been caught on line 1, so any checked exception that comes afterwards should be unreachable. If I delete line 2, line 3 will remain reachable. Exceptions are not exempt from compile-time checking. Thanks in advance for clarifying this for me.

```
public class Ape {
    public void run() {
        try {
            spit();
        } catch (HurtException e) { //line 1
            System.out.println("f");
        } catch (LimpException ex) { //line 2: Unreachable, HurtException already caught
            System.out.println("e");
        } catch (Exception ee) {     //line 3: Compiles, why?
            System.out.println("r");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Ape().run();
    }

    public void spit() throws HurtException {
        throw new HurtException();
    }

    class LimpException extends Exception {
    }

    class HurtException extends LimpException {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler only "knows" about `HurtException` that could be thrown from `spit()` since you explicitly defined it that way. Adding `LimpException` to the `throws` part of your method signature should satisfy the compiler:

```
public void spit() throws HurtException, LimpException {
    throw new HurtException();
}
```

Anyway, if the method doesn't really throw `LimpException` itself, you basically just make your code harder to read.

Answer (score 2):

Line 3 compiles, because `Exception` is a superclass for all RuntimeExceptions and if such is thrown, it will be handled (at Runtime) with the body of `(catch Exception)` block.

The compiler can't determine if such exception will be thrown at Runtime and thus, doesn't mark it as *unreachable*